Why doesn't Delete key work in Visual Studio 2022 Property pane?
If I create a Windows Forms .Net 4.8 project in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.10.1, then click into the Properties pane to modify a property, such as the "Text" property of the form, I can use the Backspace key to remove characters from the Text property, but if I press the Delete key on the keyboard, nothing happens, whether I have the cursor at the beginning, middle, or end of the property value, and whether or not I have highlighted any text in the property value.
This also occurs within Collection editors, such as the ListViewItem Collection editor.
NOTE that I am editing String properties, so they should support the Delete key if they support the Backspace key.
Is the Delete key intentionally disabled, or is this a bug?
Maybe nobody else uses the Delete key, but sometimes it makes sense to use it based on cursor position, and I automatically press it out of habit.
Can anyone explain why this happens and/or how to fix it?

Delete key works fine for me in the Properties window. Maybe try resetting your settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/personalizing-the-visual-studio-ide?view=vs-2022#default-environment-settings-for-visual-studio

I don't think this is related to resetting the configuration, because it is a new installation of VS 2022, without customizations made.  The delete key works in the main code window, but not in the Properties box.

So just to confirm, you did reset your settings and still have the same behavior?

This is a new install of VS 2022 on a fresh Windows installation.  So there would be no settings to reset, right?

In theory yes, however something has changed somewhere. We are trying to get to that cause.

OK I did the reset. First I chose "General" to restore to default, but it said there was 1 error: could not restore all General settings.  Then I chose Visual C# environment and it said there was 1 error but there was no description.  I closed and reopened VS2022 and the delete key still doesn't work.  I think it's a bug, not a configuration option.  I bet they were using custom text boxes in the properties pane and forgot to implement the delete key properly.  I was just hoping someone knew a workaround.

They implemented it fine, behaves as expected for most.  First red flag here is there was an error when you tried resetting the settings. Sounds like your VS config or VS install is jacked. Try re-installing VS. Maybe someone more knowledgeable will chime in.

Regarding your situation that the Delete key does not work in Visual Studio 2022, I also tested it and found that when your cursor is positioned at a certain place, pressing the Delete key will only delete the text to the right of the cursor. This is not only the case in the property window, but also when writing program code. If you are different from me, I think you can reset your VS: Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset All Settings.

This is a new installation of VS 2022, with no customizations made to the settings.  This also occurred on another computer with VS 2019.  The delete key simply does nothing when pressed, when the cursor is in a Property text box.  It works correctly in the main code window.

Well, but it does respond after I tried it. It is really strange that there is no response in the text of the property window. You can try to bring up the virtual keyboard and try it again to see if it works. If it still doesn't work, it may be related to some specific settings in your system. If you really want this function, you should probably reinstall your system.

Really? that's a terrible answer.  "Reinstall your system" to fix a config issue in Visual Studio???
